# Should i get ubuntu to replace windows 10 on my pc?

Tags: 16.04, windows

i am thinking of installing ubuntu on my pc. Would it be easy for beginners? what desktop environment should i use? Would it be better and more reliable than my windows 10 pc? Thanks-Liam

Comment: Have you thought of instead using a virtual machine or alternatively, dual booting Ubuntu & Windows?

Comment: You can create a [LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) and, instead of installing, you can try it **as if it were installed in your PC**. That will give you a real feel of how it is. I cannot recommend it enough. Even if you play videogames (a reason why I find many people don't use Linux), it is a very decent alternative, improving every day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu is better at many things than Windows, especially:

- file sharing
- overall system security and integrity
- lack of bloatware
- stability through complete removal of software when you uninstall something

But it is weaker than Windows for a few things, such as:

- gaming (most games do not have a Linux version)
- recent hardware support (there's always a delay)

The learning curve isn't as bad as it used to be just a few years ago, and I find the default desktop environment (Unity) to be most satisfactory. As has been suggested, you may wish to have a dual-boot system, meaning you would have Windows and Ubuntu running side-by-side. Ubuntu has a boot menu (called `GRUB`) that will allow you to select which OS to boot. The best way to have a dual-boot system is with separate OS's on separate hard drives, but many people run both OS's on the same hard drive without trouble.

---

**Some helpful links..**

- Download Ubuntu Desktop - "[Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop)"
- Download Ubuntu flavours - "[Ubuntu flavours](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu-flavours)"
- Dual boot Windows 10 & Ubuntu - "[WindowsDualBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)"
- Ubuntu info, help, etc. - "[Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/)"
- Getting started w/ Ubuntu - "[Get Started with Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.linux.com/learn/get-started-ubuntu-1604)"